# Cannot print when RDPing

Tags: remote-desktop, printer

I have a Windows XP computer that belongs to a Workgroup.  It prints to a local Canon USB printer.  I use it to RDP into a Windows Server 2003 machine.  The Windows Server 2003 machine belongs to a domain.  During the RDP, I select the option of including 'Printers' in the 'Local Resources'.  However, I am unable to print from the Remote server to the local Canon printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Has printer redirection been enabled on the server?  If the server doesn't permit it, there is nothing you can do on the client.

With Windows 2003, there is a lot of issues with printer drivers and printing over RDP.  It could be that a compatible driver mapping could not be found.  If Citrix was installed, or if you had Windows 2008, then a generic driver would be used.

Comment: I enabled the printer redirect, but that did not help.  I ended up printing to a PDF printer (using CuteFTP) and saving the results to a file.  It is not the most elegant solution, but a solution nonetheless.  Thanks for your help!